# CUDA kernel template instantiation causing compilation error

Tags: c++, templates, cuda

I am trying to define a template CUDA kernel for logical operations on an image. The code looks like this:

```
#define AND 1
#define OR 2
#define XOR 3
#define SHL  4
#define SHR 5 

template<typename T, int opcode> 
__device__ inline T operation_lb(T a, T b)
{
    switch(opcode)
    {
    case AND:
        return a & b;
    case OR:
        return a | b;
    case XOR:
        return a ^ b;
    case SHL:
        return a << b;
    case SHR:
        return a >> b;
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}

//Logical Operation With A Constant
template<typename T, int channels, int opcode> 
__global__ void kernel_logical_constant(T* src, const T val, T* dst, int width, int height, int pitch)
{
    const int xIndex = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    const int yIndex = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if(xIndex >= width || yIndex >= height) return;

    unsigned int tid = yIndex * pitch + (channels * xIndex);

    #pragma unroll
    for(int i=0; i<channels; i++)
        dst[tid + i] = operation_lb<T,opcode>(src[tid + i],val);
}
```

The problem is that when I instantiate the kernel for bit shifting, the following compilation error arises

> Error 1   error : Ptx assembly aborted due to errors

The kernel instants are like this:

```
template __global__ void kernel_logical_constant<unsigned char,1,SHL>(unsigned char*,unsigned char,unsigned char*,int,int,int);
```

There are 19 more instants like this for `unsigned char`, `unsigned short`, 1 and 3 channels and all logical operations. But only the bit shifting instances, i.e. `SHL` and `SHR` cause error. When I remove these instances, the code compiles and works perfectly.
The code also works if I replace the bit shifting with any other operation inside the `operation_lb` device function.
I was wondering if this had anything to do with the amount of ptx code generated due to so many different instances of the kernel.

I am using CUDA 5.5, Visual Studio 2010, Windows 8 x64. Compiling for `compute_1x, sm_1x`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Will something like `a << int(b)` help?

Comment: @Eric... nope. still not compiling.

Comment: Will a non-template version of SHR work? or a template specialization for SHR rather than `switch`.

Comment: Can you please provide a complete reproducer of the compile problem?  When I attempt to create my own, as indicated [here](http://pastebin.com/nu8UYpiF), it compiles correctly.  Yes I realize I am using linux not windows.  Since the problem appears to be on the device compiler side, I'm not sure linux vs. windows should make a difference.  I'll switch to windows if I discover that your stated reproducer compiles cleanly under linux.

Comment: @RobertCrovella... Actually the code is part of a bigger library (CUVILib). When I created a same scenario just like you did, in a separate project, it compiled perfectly.This kernel is a part of arithmetic and logical operations module of the library. It contains 184 unique instants of 6 template kernels. Could it be the cause of the problem?

Comment: I'm not really sure.  So far I am unable to reproduce the problem based on the information you have provided.  This type of inefficient troubleshooting is exactly why SO states:  "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance. "  Voting to close.

Comment: I am struggling to understand what sort of answer you are expecting here if you can't provide a repro case. I would start diagnosis by building a standlone project and adding code until the problem reappears, then dump the PTX and have a look at it. There used to be a limit of 1 million instructions mentioned in the documentation. Check if you are hitting it. Until you can define the problem, I don't see how [SO] can be of much help.....

Comment: @RobertCrovella Ok I figured out the problem. The default flag of `compute_10, sm_10` was still on, and this was causing the error. The compilation is successful only on compute 2.x and 3.x. I suppose bit shifting is not supported on compute 1.x.

Comment: @sgar91: Bit shifting is supported on all CUDA capable devices, and there are hardware instructions to do this. You are probably hitting a compiler bug. sm_1x platforms use Open64 for the front of the compiler, while the compiler front for later platforms is NVVM (which is based on LLVM), thus the different behavior observed. I would suggest filing a bug report with a self-contained repro case attached. The bug reporting form is linked from the registered developer website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original question specified that the poster was using `compute_20, sm_20`.  With that, I was not able to reproduce the error using the code [here](http://pastebin.com/nu8UYpiF).  However, in the comments it was pointed out that actually `sm_10` was being used.  When I switch to compiling for `sm_10` I am able to reproduce the error.

It *appears* to be a bug in the compiler.  I say this simply because I do not believe that the compiler should generate code that the assembler cannot handle.  However beyond that I have no knowledge of the underlying root cause.  I have filed a bug report with NVIDIA.

In my limited testing, it seems to only happen with `unsigned char` not `int`.

As a possible workaround, for cc2.0 and newer devices, specify `-arch=sm_20` when compiling.

Comment: Thankyou for your help. For now I can use multiplication as an alternative to shifting for `sm 1.x`, until the bug is resolved.

Comment: The problem happens with `char`, `unsigned char`, `short` and `unsigned short` only.